# Wicked_PDF unable to render SVG, canvas or PNG graphics

Tags: d3.js, wicked-pdf

I am trying to render some charts using D3 and wicked_pdf. The charts show up fine when I enable the show_as_html flag. But when I render the PDFs itself, only the axes show up. The chart area itself is blank. I know the JavaScript executes since the axes are rendered after the chart content.
[image: Actual chart]
[image: Rendered chart]
I tried converting the SVG to a canvas object using canvg.

```
canvg($(this).find('#canvas')[0], $('<div>').append($(picture).clone()).html(), { ignoreMouse: true, ignoreAnimation: true })
```

No change. Then, I converted the SVG to a PNG image using:

```
$(this).find('#chart').append("<img id='as' src='" + $(this).find('#canvas')[0].toDataURL() + "'>").show()
```

Still no change. However, when I insert a similar png image into the document as a static image using `wicked_pdf_image_tag`, the correct image is rendered. 
How do I get wicked_pdf to render the images correctly? I don't care about the format as long as the chart is rendered properly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately @TheMcMurder's answer will not help as wicked_pdf uses wkhtmltopdf. Furthermore, this is actually an issue for wkhtmltopdf not wicked_pdf. I've been working on the same issue with Chart.js (which uses  elements).

Here is a link to two threads on the whhtmltopdf Google Group about the issue

- [Asking for canvas support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/wkhtmltopdf-general/canvas)

And here is a thread discussing what might be the same issue on Github

- [Charts not working with wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1964)

Some basic searching points to phantom.js as a possible alternative but I haven't tried it yet.

> can't post link because my rep is too low, but Google has you covered

Good luck and let us know if you make any progress.

Comment: i don't think this is an issue with `wkhtmltopdf`. I have the latest 0.12.x version of `wkhtmltopdf` and it generates expected pdf with charts. But `wicked_pdf` doesn't.

Comment: Wicked PDF just wraps wkhtmltopdf. What version of wkhtmltopdf is your setup of wicked pdf using?

Comment: Its the same as I mentioned in my previous comment `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt)`.
I found that my charts were not displaying in a pdf bcz it was not calling the `js` function I created for graph generation.
I then just included my `js` file with the `wicked_pdf_javascript_include` helper tag and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you can try using http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ I've found that this does a better job displaying the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. With a localhost setup the solution for me was to save the full web page to html(mouse menu button and save page as complete web page). Then execute:

```
wkhtmltopdf -O Landscape -s A3 saved-page.html output.pdf
```

You might need to add --javascript-delay 10000 too, but maybe not.

It's weird but d3.js chart in svg is being rendered this way, but it's not rendered if you place the url...